# weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl does not have the property 'request'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, weblogic

I have a Spring MVC application that I developped using Apache Tomcat. I had no problem whatsoever with this application, however, it is now time to migrate it to Oracle Weblogic. Once the application deploys, Weblogic really starts to lose its marbles. It throws the exact same error multiple times per second. The stacktrace is alway identical and contains the following error:

```
[ServletContext@15511833[app:nl.crm_war_0.0.1-SNAPSHOT module:-crm-fase-2-export path:null spec-version:3.0], 
request: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@e56d87
[ GET /-crm-fase-2-export HTTP/1.1 Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_05 Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2 Connection: keep-alive ]] 
Root cause of ServletException. javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl' does not have the property 'request'.     
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:664) at     
javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:293) at 
javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188) at 
com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138) at 
com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183) at
com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224) at 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.ELHelper.evaluate(ELHelper.java:32) at 
jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._layouts.__header._jsp__tag2(__header.java:310) at 
jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._layouts.__header._jspService(header.jsp:9) at 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:576) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:480) at 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:162) at 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspContextWrapper.include(JspContextWrapper.java:240) at 
jsp_servlet._tags.__template_45_with_45_header_tag.doTag(__template_45_with_45_header_tag.java:147) at 
jsp_servlet._web_45_inf._pages._system.__dashboard._jspService(__dashboard.java:97) at 
weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:576) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:272) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:341) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:238) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3363) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333) at 
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at 
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) at 
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124) at 
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564) at 
weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254) at 
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295) at  
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

The stacktrace seem to indicate that there is something wrong with a few of my JSP files, however, removing these completely or removing (parts of) the code from these files does not solve the problem. In fact, after removing these files completely, the error persists.

After hours wasted googling this problem, I am on the verge of throwing my laptop out of the window. Does anyone have any clue as to what is wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you format that stacktrace better?  It's really hard to read right now.  Add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line and it will display as fixed-width text and be easier for people to help diagnose.

Comment: Sorry, added the code formats

Comment: It seems like it's looking for a public "request" property on ServletRequestImpl.  Can you post the code for ServletRequestImpl?

Comment: I'd love to, but that's not part of my code. I'm assuming that's a part of some Weblogic JAR.